# Django Container Fails to Find Settings Module Specified in Environment Variable

Tags: python, django, docker, django-rest-framework

I'm encountering a persistent issue when deploying my Django application using Docker. Despite specifying the settings module in my environment variable, Django throws an `OSError` indicating it cannot find the file.

Here's the error I'm getting:
`OSError: No such file: /code/app/settings/environments/.py`

This suggests that Django is looking for a `.py` file without a preceding filename in the `/code/app/settings/environments/` directory.

Moreover, when I remove the development.py file, Django raises a different error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.settings.environments.development'`

Here's how I have my `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` set in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
`services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile.backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend/:/code/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.environments.development
    env_file:
     - backend/.env
    depends_on:
      - database

  database:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - backend/.env
    ports:
      - "5434:5432"

volumes:
  postgres_data:`
```

```
`FROM python:3.11-slim

ARG DJANGO_ENV

ENV DJANGO_ENV=${DJANGO_ENV} \
  PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1 \
  PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
  PYTHONHASHSEED=random \
  PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
  PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
  PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  gcc \
  python3-dev \
  libpq-dev \
  netcat-openbsd \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /code

COPY backend/requirements /code/requirements
COPY backend/app/settings /code/app/settings
RUN pip install -r requirements/development.txt

COPY backend /code

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["sh", "run.sh"]`
```

In backend/.env file I have only DB settings.
In run.sh file script check if database has been started and then run:

```
`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`
```

I've verified that the development.py file exists at the specified location in the container.

My Dockerfile copies the entire backend directory to /code in the container, and the docker-compose.yml is set to mount the backend directory to /code.

I've already tried rebuilding the Docker image without cache using `docker-compose build --no-cache`, and I've double-checked the environment variables. However, the issue persists.

What might be causing Django to not recognize the correct settings file in the Docker environment, and how can I resolve this?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using 1 settings file for each environment? Say for example: `development.py`, `test.py`, etc? Or is it main `settings.py` + `development.py` / `test.py` etc ?

Can you show the folder structure?